# Basic exponent help

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have what I know is rather simple problem I need to solve and I'm having a brain meltdown. I don't do a lot of math in my daily work and haven't solved a problem like this in a while.  Can someone please refresh me. How do I solve for $c$ in the following?
$$320 = 4c^2 + 3000c$$

Comment: Use quadratic formula or Wolframalpha : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=320+%3D+4c%5E2+%2B+3000c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just rewrite the equation to the form $ac^2+bc+d=0$, so for your case $4c^2+3000c-320=0$ and use the formula to solve quadratic equations:

$c=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2+4ad}}{2a}$, and so your equations answers will be $c_1=0.1066$ and $c_2=-750.1$